# sqlalchemy trying to count parents in database efficiently

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The following function rank counts the parents in the database properly, but I have to send it like Group.query.(user_id==1).rank(0, Group.query.(user_id==1)) which does not seem very efficient. Is there a better way to write this function?

```
class Group(db.Model):
    #data
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    #relationships
    parent_id=db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'))
    children=db.relationship('Group', backref=db.backref('parent', remote_side=[id]))

    def rank(self, count, parent):
        if parent.parent:
            count=count+1
            parent.rank(count, parent.parent)
        else:
            return count
```

Comment: In other words are you trying to count the nesting level? What DB are you using? Also, why are you passing the same instance as the `parent` argument to `rank()`, instead of using `self`?

Comment: I'm using sqlite for the database. I tried using self but it just kept returning 0.  My idea is if you have 5 parents your rank is 5. Since the database is self referencial I need these to be able to change when a new apparent is attached as a root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the instance that you're calling the method on as another argument is redundant, and your function is also missing a return statement. Not to mention performing the same query twice just to get going. You could and should simply use `self` and `self.parent`. Your recursive function's base case would be when there is no parent:

```
class Group(db.Model):

    def rank(self):
        if not self.parent:
            return 0

        else:
            # Python has no TCO, so no point in trying to
            # use an accumulator
            return 1 + self.parent.rank()
```

But you're right that this might not perform ideally, if you have deeply nested structures, but for just a few levels of nesting the simple recursion might beat more complex methods. Every first access of `Group.parent` on an instance will issue a new SELECT statement to the DB. You could take the operation to your data, or in other words perform it in the DB. Tree like structures can be handled with a [recursive Common Table Expression](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
def rank(self):
    cls = type(self)
    parents = db.session.query(cls.parent_id).\
        filter_by(id=self.id).\
        cte(recursive=True)

    parent_alias = db.aliased(parents)
    group_alias = db.aliased(cls)

    parents = parents.union_all(
        db.session.query(group_alias.parent_id).
            filter(group_alias.id == parent_alias.c.parent_id))

    # Subtract one so that only the parents count
    return db.session.query(db.func.count() - 1).\
        select_from(parents).\
        scalar()
```

You could also possibly turn this in to a [hybrid property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html), if you need the count SQL side some time.

Comment: Strong is the Python in this one.